# table or view does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, mybatis

using mybatis for querying with database and

throwing below error,

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
### The error may exist in com/pulse/jdbcservices/cob/pulset24user/PulseT24UserMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT userid,username,classification,attributes from PULSET24USER
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

And my mapper class code is

```
@Select("SELECT userid,username,classification,attributes from PULSET24USER")
public List<PulseT24User> getAllRecords();
```

please give me any solution to solve this problem

Comment: Have you checked the database to see if PULSET24USER table exists? What happens if you run your query in a database client?

Comment: Check that the table `PULSET24USER` exists in the db schema your code  connects to or that a synonym to the table exists.Make sure that the db user has the `select` privilege on the table. If some of the terms are Double Dutch to you, get your dba or a colleague to asisst you.

Comment: what database are you trying to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible that you missed to set up the right permission for the view or table PULSET24USER. Please also check the correct spelling.

Comment: SAME QUERY WORKS IN SQL DEVELOPER

Comment: ...and please recheck if you are connected to the correct database instance.

Comment: ya i have connected to correct database and other queries are executed successfully in that same database but different table

Answer (score 0):

1- Validate if your table exist in SQL Developper (can do it with simple select...) multiple way to do it.

```
select * from PULSET24USER;
```

2- I suspect you are using a different user from SQL Developper than from your Java program, and then the error is caused by a missing synonym/schema name.

From ora-code website:

> ORA-00942:    table or view does not exist
>   Cause:  The table or view entered does not exist, a synonym that is not allowed here was used, or a view was referenced where a table is required. Existing user tables and views can be listed by querying the data dictionary. Certain privileges may be required to access the table. If an application returned this message, the table the application tried to access does not exist in the database, or the application does not have access to it.
>   Action: Check each of the following:
>   the spelling of the table or view name.
>   that a view is not specified where a table is required.
>   that an existing table or view name exists.
>   Contact the database administrator if the table needs to be created or if user or application privileges are required to access the table.
>
> Also, if attempting to access a table or view in another schema, make
>   certain the correct schema is referenced and that access to the object
>   is granted.

Hope that's helping you.